# Automatically Hosting Multiple Subdomains for the Same ReactJS Webapp on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I've deployed a ReactJS webapp on AWS Amplify and its current domain is app.example.com. I'd like to provide functionality where users can specify their own subdomain (e.g., test1.example.com, test2.example.com) and have it automatically point to the same webapp. Essentially, all of these subdomains will be CNAME aliases of app.example.com.

To explain further:

A user specifies a subdomain name (e.g., "test1").
The system automatically sets up test1.example.com to point to app.example.com.
Given that the main app is on AWS Amplify, how can I achieve this automatic subdomain creation and pointing?

Here's what I've considered/attempted so far:

Manually adding CNAME records in Route53 for each subdomain. But I'm looking for a more automated solution.

I am using Nodejs and Reactjs

Any guidance, including potential AWS services or configurations, would be greatly appreciated!